# Having trouble with query-based Realms

Tags: swift, realm

Sorry, my subject isn't very specific.

I'm dealing with managing multiple users in my realm and having some problems. I have a user register with their email and name, then when realm logs in and creates a `SyncUser`, I create a new `YpbUser` object with the email, name, and `SyncUser.current.identity` in `YpbUser.id`.

When a user logs in, I want to use their email to look up whether there's an existing `YpbUser` for their email. I'm doing it this way so in the future if someone uses username/password and then uses Google auth (not yet implemented), those `SyncUser`s can get to the same `YpbUser`.

Below is my code for checking for an existing `YpbUser`, along with my realm setup code. The problem I'm having is that it usually, but not always, fails to find a `YpbUser` even if that user exists (I'm looking at the `YpbUser` list in realm studio and the user with that email is definitely there!)

Inspecting from within `existingUser(for:in:)`, `users` is usually 0, but it sometimes non-zero.

I assume the issue lies somewhere in the fact that I'm pretty much just guessing on how to use `SyncSubscription.observe`.

Please help?

```
    fileprivate func openRealmWithUser(user: SyncUser) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            let config = user.configuration(realmURL: RealmConstants.realmURL, fullSynchronization: false, enableSSLValidation: true, urlPrefix: nil)
            self?.realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)

            let songSub = self?.realm?.objects(Song.self).subscribe()
            let usersSub = self?.realm?.objects(YpbUser.self).subscribe()

            self?.usersToken = usersSub?.observe(\.state, options: .initial) { state in
                if !(self?.proposedUser.email.isEmpty)! {
                    self?.findYpbUser(in: (self?.realm)!)
                }
            }
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: Storyboard.LoginToNewRequestSegue, sender: nil)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func findYpbUser(in realm: Realm) {
        if proposedUser != YpbUser() { // self.proposedUser.email gets set from the login method
            let existingUser = YpbUser.existingUser(for: proposedUser, in: realm)
            guard existingUser == nil else { // If we find the YpbUser, set as current:
                try! realm.write {
                    pr("YpbUser found: \(existingUser!)")
                    YpbUser.current = existingUser }
                return
            }
            pr("YpbUser not found.") // i.e., SyncUser set, but no YpbUser found. i.e., creating a new YpbUser
            createNewYpbUser(for: proposedUser, in: realm)
        }
    }

extension YpbUser {
    class func existingUser (for proposedUser: YpbUser, in realm: Realm) -> YpbUser? {
        let users = realm.objects(YpbUser.self)
        let usersWithThisEmail = users.filter("email = %@", proposedUser.email)
        if let emailUser = usersWithThisEmail.first {
            return emailUser
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.) what is the desired behavior 2.) what does it do instead 3.) `SyncSubscription.observe` isn't in your code

Comment: Is it possible that you are not always using the default `Realm` instance?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: 1. A YpbUser object with the current logged in user's email is found and assigned to 'YpbUser.current'. 2. 'existingUser(for:in:)' sometimes finds zero users (with the same email of not) although 'proposedUser.email' is always non-empty. 3. I'm referring to 'self?.usersToken = usersSub.observe(...)'

Comment: @InfinityJames I’m fairly sure I only ever assign self.realm once and afterward only use a reference to that same realm, there’s never another realm. But maybe it has something to do with the length of time realm = Realm(configuration:) takes, such that sometimes it’s still nil when we get to the subscription lines?

Comment: Are you certain that your subscription has completed? You might want to check the state.